# For what value does this integral converge to $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I was computing integrals using WolframAlpha and I found for many complex numbers $p, q, r$ which are not real numbers, this integral **always** converged to $0$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)} dx$$

I tried to prove this and I got a partial fraction decomposition of this function i.e.

(1) for different three $p, q, r$
$$\frac{1}{(p-q)(p-r)}\frac{1}{x-p}+\frac{1}{(q-p)(q-r)}\frac{1}{x-q}+\frac{1}{(r-p)(r-q)}\frac{1}{x-r}$$

(2) for doubled $p$ and single $q$
$$\frac{1}{p-q}\frac{1}{(x-p)^2}-\frac{1}{(p-q)^2}\frac{1}{x-p}+\frac{1}{(p-q)^2}\frac{1}{x-q}$$

(3) and the rest is of course
$$\frac{1}{(x-p)^3}$$

and then for (3) I could prove my assumption.
But when it comes to (1) and (2) it was not very easy for me. Does anyone know about this integral? Is my assumption correct? Thanks in advance.

**Edit** And I'm not also sure whether I really can use the normal riemann integral method to this function, because it has complex coefficients.

Comment: note that $$\frac{(q-r) \log (x-p)+(r-p) \log (x-q)+(p-q) \log (x-r)}{(p-q) (p-r) (q-r)}$$ is the indefinite integral

Comment: The easiest way to do this is through contour integrals and the residue theorem.

Comment: There will be plenty of choices for $p,q,r$ such that the integral is not zero. For example if $p$ is above the real axis and $q,r$ are below it, then the integral equals $(2\pi i)/[(p-q)(p-r)],$ which is never $0.$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What kind of $\log$'s are those? Certainly not ordintary logarithms of real analysis.

Comment: I said $p, q, r$ are not real numbers...